# In which table the products quantity are stored?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

What is **database table** `name`which store the **product quantity** in **Magento 1.9**

Comment: Hello i posted the database schema relation of `cataloginventory_stock_item` hope it help you a bit.Thank You

Answer (score 2):

First of if you want to see the relation between all the tables then you can refer [this link](http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png)

`cataloginventory_stock_item` have `qty` column which holds the qty details.

[image: schema]

main table for products in Magento:

`catalog_product_entity`

Above table is the main table, for the child tables table names as `catalog_product_entity_`prefix.

`catalog_product_entity_datetime` for **Date attributes are stored here.** 
 `catalog_product_entity_decimal` for **Product price related values.**

`catalog_category_entity_text` for **category attributes**

To know more visit below mentioned links

1. https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024879/Catalog+Database+Tables
2. https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/list-of-product-tables-in-magento/
3. http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png
4. https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/infographic-magento-1-vs-magento-2-database-structure/

Answer (score 1):

Database table name that store product quantity is called `cataloginventory_stock_item`.